# Como acessar um valor que foi colocado via JavaScript de um site via VBA?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando acessar os valores que aparecem no site: http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/BoletimOnline1.asp?caminho=&pagetype=pop&Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DI1

Não consegui acessar os valores nem por hyperlink direto no excel, nem criando uma querytable via VBA. Dos dois modos os valores não retornam. 
Pesquisando na internet, vi que os valores que são inputados via JavaScript não podem ser retirados dessa forma, até porque os valores não possuem um ID.
Bem, olhando o código fonte consigo ver como os valores são inputados por um Script, mas não faço ideia de como trazer esses valores do site para o Excel via VBA.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o trecho do código fonte onde os valores são inputados, estão em negrito. Quando vocês forem acessar o site os valores estarão diferentes dos abaixo pois os valores são cotações de bolsa.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JScript'>
 tab_A = tab_A + 'TR'
            "tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,650</TD>';
            tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,640</TD>';
            tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,650</TD>';
            tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,643</TD>';
            tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,641</TD>';
            tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,641</TD>';
            tab_C = tab_C + '<TD ALIGN="right" CLASS="tabelaConteudo1">13,649</TD>';"

...
            </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Da uma lida aqui depois - http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo

Comment: Procure por um webservice e veja como usá-lo.
Ferramentas de programação podem chamar o serviço e às vezes pelo browser você mesmo poderá chamá-lo, irá receber um formato diferente de html mas que pode facilmente ser colocado no excel.

Comment: Talvez [essa pergunta no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64278/api-para-cotação-de-bolsa-de-valores) te ajude a achar uma alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

O problema, nesse caso, é que os valores são colocados na página por um script executado *depois* que a página carrega, pelo motor do navegador.

Então, você vai ter que usar um navegador. Por sorte, existe um que você pode usar e manipular por meio do VBA. É o controle ActiveX WebBrowser, que nada mais é do que uma versão encapsulada do Internet Explorer, operando como se fosse o IE7.

Você pode fazer o que foi sugerido [aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2712854), ou criar um UserForm e colocar o WebBrowser nele.

O importante é você navegar até a página que lhe interessa. Você pode fazer isso com este comando:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/BoletimOnline1.asp?caminho=&pagetype=pop&Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DI1")
```

Você vai ter que ter criado uma Sub para manipular o evento `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted`, que vai disparar quando a página terminar de ser carregada, e acessar a propriedade `WebBrowser.Document` que te devolve um objeto que te dá acesso ao DOM (*Document Object Model*) daquela página, permite ler (e até mesmo alterar) os elementos HTML e seus estados.

Para fazer isso, você vai ter que analisar o código HTML da página para saber quais elementos você deve ler, quais valores você deve alterar e quais eventos do DOM você precisa disparar para obter o que você precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui abrir a página aqui.
Enfim, pelo o que vi em seu exemplo, a variável é publica, certo?

Caso seja, através do método `InternetExplorer.Document.parentWindow.execScript`, você pode criar um elemento HTML, inserir o texto da variável no HTML dele e depois acessar esse elemento com o VBA.

Se for fazer dessa forma, acredito que ficaria algo assim:

```
  Dim IE as New InternetExplorer
  Dim Doc as HTMLDocument

  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate2 "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/BoletimOnline1.asp?caminho=&pagetype=pop&Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DI1"

  Do While IE.readystate  READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

  Set Doc = IE.Document
  Doc.parentWindow.execScript "var p = document.createElement('p'); p.id = 'vba'; p.innerHTML = tab_C"

  MsgBox Doc.getElementById('vba').innerHTML
```

Agora se você não puder/quiser usar um navegador, você pode pode simplesmente fazer um http request para a página e se virar com o HTML dele (que provavelmente vai conter o texto que você quer).

É dessa forma que eu faria, e usaria expressão regular para me virar com o HTML.

Caso esteja interessado:

```
    Dim WHTTP As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim HTML As String
    Dim RegEx As New RegExp
    Dim Matches As MatchCollection
    Dim Match As Match
    Dim Valores As New Collection
    Dim i As Double

    With WHTTP
        .Open "GET", "http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/BoletimOnline1.asp?caminho=&pagetype=pop&Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DI1", False
        .send

        If .Status  200 Then
            Debug.Print "Requisição retornou status " & .Status & " (" & .statusText & ")"
            Stop
        End If

        HTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set WHTTP = Nothing

    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\d+(,?)\d{3}(?=)"

        Set Matches = .Execute(HTML)
    End With

    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To Matches.Count - 1
            Set Match = Matches.Item(i)

            Valores.Add Match.Value
        Next i
    End If
```

No fim desse código, a coleção `Valores` terá todos os resultados que batem com a expressão regular `\d+(,?)\d{3}(?=</TD>)`